# Mobile live synchronization (eg Trello): sockets?

Tags: android, ios, sockets, synchronization, trello

I was wondering how live synchronization mechanisms such as the one used by Trello work.

For example when I move a card from the website, the board is immediately refreshed on the iPhone too. As Push Notifications are not reliable, I suppose a sort of open connection/socket stream is used under the hood.

socket.io quotes Trello among its users: does anyone have any reference about Trello's mobile implementation?

Thanks,
DAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trello uses a combination of WebSockets and polling to perform instant updates.  Most clients use WebSockets all the time; the few that don't support WebSockets use short HTTP polling instead.  It also uses a single HTTP poll to "catch up" after losing a WebSocket connection and reconnecting.

The iOS and Android apps connect using socket.io clients that are locked down to only the WebSocket transport.  The web client uses raw WebSockets.  On the backend, socket.io is used only to support the handshake and protocol expected by the iOS/Android apps; all of the pubsub/message routing is custom.

Answer (score 1):

I've no excact documentation about Trello but some ideas:
You could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor the network traffic between your iDevice and Trello.

Socket.io is a very nice thing and could be used with iOS (see [here](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc)). It should be possible to live update a view with socket.io

Comment: Here's the network traffic generated by Trello on app opening read by Charles:
Overview -> http://cl.ly/image/3W0Q3Y3w1m19
Request -> http://cl.ly/image/2y0x410H0r0B
No response -> http://cl.ly/image/2w2e2F1D0a0K
It's not really clear to me, there no response, the request failed ("Remote host closed connection during handshake") and the HTTP method is CONNECT. Anyway the answer should be yes, it seems that a socket stream is being used

Comment: I think you tried to monitor https traffic without the right charles configuration. [See this help page](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) to monitor https traffic, too.

Comment: But I don't know if Charles support Websocket (the thing which socket.io is build on). Fiddler should support Websockets.